# Wrong encoding in originalname file-uploading

Tags: forms, express, file-upload, multer

I am sending a file named: .jpg. But the server returns: ðð.jpg.
Why does the server have a different encoding for the filename? How to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form
    action="/form"
    method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    accept-charset="UTF-8"
  >
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**server code**

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import multer from "multer";
dotenv.config()
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(express.json());
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.get("/:id?", async (req:any,res:any,next:any)=>{
    res.sendFile("views/index.html",  {root: __dirname })
})

app.post("/form", upload.fields([{ name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 }]), async (req: any,res:any,next:any)=>{
    res.send(req.files['avatar']? req.files['avatar'][0].originalname : 'Error');
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, async ()=>{
    console.log("Server start at "+process.env.PORT)
})
```